# Verify the user activity on third party site

Tags: php, cookies

Would like to know the method for those survey site, how they able to check the user activities over the next website? Let say i click a button, and i want to make sure user do something like click the button of site B for 50 times, then the site A will notice about this.

Please advice. Thanks!!

Comment: Through a communication way. It could for example an through an api.

Comment: As Cristian, a communication method is needed. Both sender and receiver websites must settle an agreement over a common protocol and its APIs in order to be able to verify user activities.

Comment: @CristianBitoi Any idea how if i know from the site B i'm from site A?

Comment: @SigNaL89 Any idea how if i know from the site B i'm from site A?

Comment: First create a ticket using APIs in site A, and then send the user with that ticket. So site A can easily recognize the user with its ticket and the source it came from.

Comment: @SigNaL89 , can you please let me know how can i recognize the same user? by IP? please advice :D

Comment: Site A has an API which gives site B a ticket (e.g. a 64byte unique string) and stores it on its own db along with its source (which is site B) and everything. Then site B sends the user using this ticket to site A (e.g. site-a.com/?ticket=BlahBlaah...). Now site A can track this user and it knows that this ticket was produced for site B (which is the source in DB). etc.